# ActionBar and title not dissapearing after changes to AndroidManifest.xml and styles.xml in nativescript

Tags: android, xml, nativescript

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.domain.project"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="25"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

And here is my `values/styles.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- theme to use FOR launch screen-->
    <style name="LaunchScreenThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!--<item name="toolbarStyle">@style/NativeScriptToolbarStyle</item>-->

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ns_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/ns_accent</item>

        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>

        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>  
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

    </style>

    <style name="LaunchScreenTheme" parent="LaunchScreenThemeBase">
    </style>

    <!-- theme to use AFTER launch screen is loaded-->
    <style name="AppThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!--<item name="toolbarStyle">@style/NativeScriptToolbarStyle</item>-->

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ns_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/ns_accent</item>

        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppThemeBase">
    </style>

    <!-- theme for actioon-bar
    <style name="NativeScriptToolbarStyleBase" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/ns_primary</item>
        <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NativeScriptToolbarStyle" parent="NativeScriptToolbarStyleBase">
    </style> -->

</resources>
```

**I can change values in android:windowFullscreen and the app goes fullscreen or not, accordingly to the boolean set**. So, I know that the **manifest file is being parsed correctly**. However, the title bar / action bar / toolbar is simply never hiding and always appears with the app in the title.

I am using this angular seed, not sure if relevant: https://github.com/TeamMaestro/angular-native-seed

I've been stuck in this for some time now, can someone help? Thanks :)

Comment: check your activity class.. did you extend it AppCompactActivity or Activity ?, your style only work in AppCompactActivity.....

Answer (score 1):

> I can change values in android:windowFullscreen and the app goes
>   fullscreen or not, accordingly to the boolean set. So, I know that the
>   manifest file is being parsed correctly. However, the title bar /
>   action bar / toolbar is simply never hiding and always appears with
>   the app in the title.

Your manifest is correct, but your **preview** is set up wrong. **You have to remember that the Android Studio preview doesn't reflect how your application will actually look when run on a real device.**

I created a dummy project to explain. Here is code that removes the action bar, similar to what you have:

```
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Which looks like this in source code:

```
   <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Now this clearly tells the app to not show an action bar, just like your theme does. However, if you look at the preview, you will see this:

[image]

So then how do you make your preview accurately reflect your theme? Well, click here:

[image]

And adjust your theme to include no action bar!
[image]

As a result, you have no action bar in the preview and in the application:
[image]

Let me know if this was helpful!

Comment: I'm running this on a real device though through ADB and usb connection

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to `style.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.NoActionBar">
       <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
       <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and add this code to `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.NoActionBar">

        <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.NoActionBar"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

i Go Through Your Code and havent found any Problem ,But Maybe There is issue with code but U can Try Compare with This style that works for me:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
```